# jquery autocomplete on element retrieved w/ ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, binding, autocomplete

I am using a simple jquery autocomplete script to search for colleges in a text field.  This same script works on another page.  On the page in question though, I retrieve the form with an ajax call and it's not working.  Did I forget something or is there an issue binding the autocomplete event to the  when it is inserted in the DOM?

AJAX Markup:

```
<input type="text" class="alumni" name="alumni0" id="alumni0" value="Academy College">
```

Script:

```
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        var availableTags;
        $(function() {
            availableTags = ["A T Still University of Health Sciences", ... ,"Abilene Christian University"];
            $(".alumni").autocomplete({
                source: availableTags
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: do you get that input field as a string via ajax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try rebinding the autocomplete event when you add the new form to the dom. More than likely what is happening is since autocomplete isn't attached with the jquery live function your new elements just don't have the event attached.

Comment: makes sense.. do you have a quick answer for how to go about that?

Comment: right after the new elements are added just repeat the "$(".alumni").autocomplete({                 source: availableTags             });         }); " part. You don't need to redefine availableTags as it already exists (as long as you aren't reloading the page too). There might be better solutions but that is what I usually do.

Comment: Beautiful!! I especially love it when ajax-y thing work for the first time - that's a good feeling!  Thanks.