# dom jquery behavior not functioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have the following function which works properly:

```
        $(function() {
                var availableTags  = <? echo htmlspecialchars($jsEnc,ENT_NOQUOTES,'utf-8');?>;

                $( "input.tags" ).autocomplete({
                    source: availableTags
                });
        });
```

On all pre-existing:`<input class="tags"/>` the function does just as it should (an autocomplete list that is a database dump).

Now, these inputs actually exist in a `<table>`, with rows that can be added or removed on the fly.

When adding the cells to the table I do the following:

`if(i== document.getElementById("soldTo").cellIndex){
element2.setAttribute('class','tags');
}`

Which basically makes the input (element2) capable of being a target (at least so I thought) of the jquery function.

I am assuming that the jquery function is not "conscious" of this new element and must be re-initialized in some way to see the new members.

Is this true? Is this done at the time of adding the new element? Some sort of `$(x).add(myBehavior)`?

> EDIT

I tried the following:

```
$("table.inventoryItems").bind("DOMSubtreeModified", function() {
alert('z');
     $( "input.tags" ).autocomplete({
       source: availableTags
      });
 });
```

and the alert also does not trigger.

Does anything seem suspicious?

Thank you

> PROPER SOLUTION EXTERNAL LINK

[jquery autocomplete on element retrieved w/ ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5407956/jquery-autocomplete-on-element-retrieved-w-ajax)

Comment: Are you using the same ID on multiple elements?

Comment: `tables` are funky beasts to manipulate, especially across browsers. Why aren't you using a list and `data-` attributes for your dataset?

Comment: yes there are multiple `input.tags`

Comment: If you modify and the DOM with jquery I don't think you would have this problem.

Comment: @JaredFarrish can you provide a link to the data attributes you are mentioning? Thanks.

Comment: [The spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/elements.html#custom-data-attribute), [HTML5 Doctor](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/) and [John Resig's blog entry](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/).

Answer (score 1):

try `DOMSubtreeModified` event:

```
$("table").bind("DOMSubtreeModified", function() {
     $( "input.tags" ).autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
     });
});
```

or you can use **[`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)** method based on how you create a new input element:

```
$("table").on("change", "input.tags", function() {
     $(this).autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
     });
});
```

Comment: I tried. See above for the test code...too tough to post in comment.